# SSRS Bullet Indentation

Tags: reporting-services, html-lists

[image: Please see the attached image]

I am using HTML tags which has bullets and rendering in a table. Space before and after Bullets is not ok. I tried changing code in CSS but it didnt help. Pls let me know how can we reduce space before and after bullet in an un ordered list.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Wingdings font for the bullet. Lower case "l" is what I use in the example below.

#### Preview

[image: screenshot_preview]

#### Design

[image: screenshot_design]

#### Report XML .rdl code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report MustUnderstand="df" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:df="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition/defaultfontfamily">
  <df:DefaultFontFamily>Segoe UI</df:DefaultFontFamily>
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="DataSource1">
      <DataSourceReference>TempSource</DataSourceReference>
      <rd:SecurityType>None</rd:SecurityType>
      <rd:DataSourceID>0d516ad5-9001-426b-9cbc-383be6a64511</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="DataSet1">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>DataSource1</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
  ( 'Example 1')
, ( 'Example 2')
, ( 'Example 3')
, ( 'Example 4')
) tbl ([Column1]) 
</CommandText>
      </Query>
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="Column1">
          <DataField>Column1</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
  <ReportSections>
    <ReportSection>
      <Body>
        <ReportItems>
          <Tablix Name="Tablix1">
            <TablixBody>
              <TablixColumns>
                <TablixColumn>
                  <Width>3.74354cm</Width>
                </TablixColumn>
              </TablixColumns>
              <TablixRows>
                <TablixRow>
                  <Height>0.6cm</Height>
                  <TablixCells>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="Textbox1">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>Column1</Value>
                                  <Style />
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>Textbox1</rd:DefaultName>
                          <Style>
                            <Border>
                              <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                              <Style>Solid</Style>
                            </Border>
                            <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                          </Style>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                  </TablixCells>
                </TablixRow>
                <TablixRow>
                  <Height>0.6cm</Height>
                  <TablixCells>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="Column1">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>  l  </Value>
                                  <Style>
                                    <FontFamily>Wingdings</FontFamily>
                                    <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                                  </Style>
                                </TextRun>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value xml:space="preserve"> </Value>
                                  <Style>
                                    <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                                  </Style>
                                </TextRun>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>=Fields!Column1.Value</Value>
                                  <Style />
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>Column1</rd:DefaultName>
                          <Style>
                            <Border>
                              <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                              <Style>Solid</Style>
                            </Border>
                            <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                          </Style>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                  </TablixCells>
                </TablixRow>
              </TablixRows>
            </TablixBody>
            <TablixColumnHierarchy>
              <TablixMembers>
                <TablixMember />
              </TablixMembers>
            </TablixColumnHierarchy>
            <TablixRowHierarchy>
              <TablixMembers>
                <TablixMember>
                  <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
                </TablixMember>
                <TablixMember>
                  <Group Name="Details" />
                </TablixMember>
              </TablixMembers>
            </TablixRowHierarchy>
            <DataSetName>DataSet1</DataSetName>
            <Top>1.16099cm</Top>
            <Left>1.92828cm</Left>
            <Height>1.2cm</Height>
            <Width>3.74354cm</Width>
            <Style>
              <Border>
                <Style>None</Style>
              </Border>
            </Style>
          </Tablix>
        </ReportItems>
        <Height>2in</Height>
        <Style />
      </Body>
      <Width>6.5in</Width>
      <Page>
        <PageHeight>29.7cm</PageHeight>
        <PageWidth>21cm</PageWidth>
        <LeftMargin>2cm</LeftMargin>
        <RightMargin>2cm</RightMargin>
        <TopMargin>2cm</TopMargin>
        <BottomMargin>2cm</BottomMargin>
        <ColumnSpacing>0.13cm</ColumnSpacing>
        <Style />
      </Page>
    </ReportSection>
  </ReportSections>
  <ReportParametersLayout>
    <GridLayoutDefinition>
      <NumberOfColumns>4</NumberOfColumns>
      <NumberOfRows>2</NumberOfRows>
    </GridLayoutDefinition>
  </ReportParametersLayout>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Cm</rd:ReportUnitType>
  <rd:ReportID>7f2c088e-84cc-4a52-954f-bdaa79ef90a1</rd:ReportID>
</Report>
```

Comment: My report has HTML tags like Bold, Italic, underline color, listed and unlisted etc along with <UL> so using Wingdings is not helping.

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: You can use more than one expression in a textbox.